# is there a libzfs equivalent of "zfs destroy -npv foo bar baz"?

Tags: zfs

I am using [py-libzfs](https://github.com/freenas/py-libzfs) on FreeBSD to list, create and destroy snapshots and it's working as expected for these basic operations, but I'm now trying to find out "how much space would be freed if I removed a couple of snapshots?".

In ZFS removing more than one snapshot can free *more* than the sum of each snapshots space, because it could end up freeing blocks that were referenced by more than one snapshot.

On the shell the correct answer to that question can be found using the command:

```
zfs destroy -npv <dataset>@<snap1>%<snap2>,<snap3>,<...>
```

I'd like to avoid having to call an external process if possible so I tried skimming through [the code](https://github.com/openzfs/openzfs) without luck and I cannot find any relevant documentation.

Is it even *possible* to get that kind of information out of libzfs? how?

Answer (score 1):

The `py-libzfs` is 1:1 wrapper around `libzfs`, so I'd take a look around `libzfs_core` and, in particular:

```
/*
 * Destroys snapshots.
 *
 * The keys in the snaps nvlist are the snapshots to be destroyed.
 * They must all be in the same pool.
 *
 * Snapshots that do not exist will be silently ignored.
 *
 * If 'defer' is not set, and a snapshot has user holds or clones, the
 * destroy operation will fail and none of the snapshots will be
 * destroyed.
 *
 * If 'defer' is set, and a snapshot has user holds or clones, it will be
 * marked for deferred destruction, and will be destroyed when the last hold
 * or clone is removed/destroyed.
 *
 * The return value will be 0 if all snapshots were destroyed (or marked for
 * later destruction if 'defer' is set) or didn't exist to begin with.
 *
 * Otherwise the return value will be the errno of a (unspecified) snapshot
 * that failed, no snapshots will be destroyed, and the errlist will have an
 * entry for each snapshot that failed.  The value in the errlist will be
 * the (int32) error code.
 */
int
lzc_destroy_snaps(nvlist_t *snaps, boolean_t defer, nvlist_t **errlist)
```

There isn't much of the documentation regarding the API, so your best friend is the source of the `zfs` command in the `/usr/src/cddl/contrib/opensolaris/cmd/zfs`.

Also, please note, that although related, OpenZFS, ZFS on Linux and ZFS on FreeBSD are different implementations, derived from one source, hence deviated over time. There is ongoing effort to unify (Open)ZFS code base for all the platforms, but at the moment we are not there yet...